# Как передать в дочерний компонет значения из стейта?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Всем привет.

Есть у меня компонент, в котором 2 инпута.

```
...
<input class="reg__label__input" type="email" disabled 
       :placeholder="$t('registrations.emailPlaceholder')" 
       v-model="$store.state.registrations.user_email">
...
<input class="reg__label__input" :type="passwdType" ref="passwdInput" 
       v-model="$store.state.registrations.password" 
       @input="eventPassInput($event)" 
       @blur="checkPlaceholder()">
...
```

Этот компонет будет использоваться в нескольких местах.

И `v-model` всегда будет разный
И всегда из `state`

Вот не могу понять, как правильно прокинуть данные с родительского компонета, что бы из дочернего я мог их изменять.

Пытался разными способами, и `props` и `computed`
Но что то явно не так.

Прошу помощи\совета у вас.
Спасибо!

Comment: Может стоить создать компонет, внутри которого будет вызов состояния из vuex и запись обратная.?

Comment: @adrug каждый раз когда я буду  использовать данный компонент, у  меня будут разные  данные из  vuex. И вот я не могу понять,  как передавать именно те данные что нужны. На пример,  у меня может быть `$store.state.registrations.user_email`, а может `$store.state.login.user_email`

Comment: Поясните зачем вам два похожих объекта?

Comment: @adrug это как пример